# node,chrome Error [ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED]: Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, express, usersession

megerr when launching chrome in headlless mode :

```
Error [ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED]: Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed
```

I'm writing a script node express,

when express receive a http request, 
the script node launch new chrome instance in headless-mode using lib [chrome_launcher](https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface) ,
do some stuff, 
and kill the istance.

the remote server is a VPS with ubuntu16.04.

to launch the webserver I connect via ssh with VPS:

$ node app_ws.js &

If the ssh connection is alive all works fine and node script can launch chrome regularly.

Instead, when I close the terminal and break-down the ssh connection (and the user session terminates) then starts the badly:

in the first request chrome is launched, OK,

from the second request onwards script cant launch chrome, the message error is:

```
Error [ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED]: Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed
```

code snippets

```
//launch chrome in hadless mode using npm lib chrome_launcher (https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface)
const chrome = await chromeLauncher.launch({
    "chromeFlags": [ '--disable-gpu', '--headless' ]
});
//Kill Chrome
chrome.kill()
```

chrome.kill() return a promise but dont catch any error

thanks from now for help